# Выбрать строку по её значению

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть DataFrame:

```
Изменение цены
-300
-100
500
```

Хочу оставить только те строки, которые содержат "-". Делаю так:

```
a = df[df["Изменение цены"].str.contains("-", na=False)]
```

Но выходит ошибка:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как устранить проблему?

Comment: Может это все таки числовые значения и нужно не на наличие `"-"` проверять, а сравнивать с нулем?

Comment: a = df[df["Изменение цены"] < 0]] ?

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо!!! Работает!!!